# 質問時に他の質問サービスとのマルチポストを明示する必要はありますか？

Tags: 討議, サポート, 質問の仕方, マルチポスト

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/27541/rss%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E3%83%8D%E3%82%A4%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%96%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%81%A7%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) で「[teratail](https://teratail.com/) とのマルチポストがある事を追記してください」というコメントがありますが、teratail などの他の質問サイトでもそれを明記する必要があるのでしょうか。

自分もスタック・オーバーフローで回答を得られない時に teratail に同じ質問を投稿することがありますが、マルチポストであるとの明記をしていません。

スタック・オーバーフロー以外のサイトでのマルチポストを明示する必要はあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 明示する必要性やそれを指摘するコメントについての話ではありませんが、マルチポスト自体の是非や対応について以前メタ投稿がありましたので参考までに： http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1766/8000

Comment: 余談ですが、Teratailはマルチポストの理由や投稿先を明記するよう、ヘルプに書かれていますすね https://teratail.com/help

Comment: @unarist teratailではマルチポストの明示が義務付けられているのですね。わざわざ調べていただきありがとうございました。

Comment: 重複候補: [スタックオーバーフローにおけるマルチポストの扱い](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1766/%e3%82%b9%e3%82%bf%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%aa%e3%83%bc%e3%83%90%e3%83%bc%e3%83%95%e3%83%ad%e3%83%bc%e3%81%ab%e3%81%8a%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b%e3%83%9e%e3%83%ab%e3%83%81%e3%83%9d%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e3%81%ae%e6%89%b1%e3%81%84)

Comment: まとまった投稿： [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)

Answer (score 19):

マルチポスト先に限らず、質問者が持っている情報は記載するべきです。

StackOverflowでの質問は力試しの題材のような問・お題では無く、質問者が実際に抱えている問題の早期解決および、知識の集積が目的です。
質問者が投稿前に調べた事、投稿後に得られた情報、全て役に立ちます。

むしろ「マルチポスト先を書いて欲しい」というのは最低限のお願いと言ってよいでしょう。
理想的には、マルチポスト先でのやりとりで得られた情報も適宜StackOverflowに合った形で取り纏め追記し、双方の投稿を適切にメンテし続ける事が求められています。

ですが質問者の置かれた状況により、質問に費せる労力も様々でしょうし、理想を言っても仕方が無いですから、これが不十分だからといってクローズにしたり、辛辣な(印象を与える)コメントを付ける事は無いと思います。

Comment: マルチポストをする場合どちらかのサイトで全く回答が得られなかった時が多いと考えられますが、どちらかのサイトで何らかの議論や回答が得られた時はその他のポストにも追記していくのがよさそうですね。

Comment: 私が Stackoverflow または taratail で見た質問に回答してあげたいと思った時、「tarateil（またはStackoverflow）にも同じ質問をしています」という一文があれば、そちらのスレッドも参照した上で、自分の調査や回答に反映するでしょう。よりよい回答を得たいと思えば、すべての情報を開示してもらった方がよいと思います。

Answer (score 4):

質問時にマルチポストを明示するかどうかは質問者の判断でかまわないと思います。

ただし、このサイトをQ&A KnowledgeBaseとして閲覧するときにはあった方が助かる事が(ごくまれですが)あります。
どこかで解決してもそれ以外では未解決のまま放置なのが多い気がするので。

質問のコメントにでもマルチポスト(先/元)が載ってれば情報としては足りるので気が付いた人が(指摘ではなく情報として)載っける分には問題無いと思います。

Comment: 確かに、すでにどちらかのサイトで解決している質問なのにあとから同じ疑問を持った人がまだ解決していない方のポストに行き着く可能性もありますね。自分も解決した場合は解決していない方のポストに解決した方のリンクを貼り付けたほうがいいと考えました。